# Mule4 Code Builder Anypoint Extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: mule4, anypoint-code-builder

I trying Anypoint Code Builder in Visual Studio Code.
When I try to start a new Design API, I have the following error in Mule DX Server:

```
    Exception in thread "dw-lang-server-language-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/api/maven/Maven
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.project.impl.simple.SimpleDependencyManager.$anonfun$resolveDependency$1(SimpleProjectKind.scala:133)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.utils.JavaLoggerForwarder$.interceptLog(JavaLoggerForwarder.scala:41)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.project.impl.simple.SimpleDependencyManager.resolveDependency(SimpleProjectKind.scala:132)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.project.impl.simple.SimpleDependencyManager.$anonfun$loadNewArtifacts$1(SimpleProjectKind.scala:127)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.project.impl.simple.SimpleDependencyManager.$anonfun$loadNewArtifacts$1$adapted(SimpleProjectKind.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:366)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.project.impl.simple.SimpleDependencyManager.loadNewArtifacts(SimpleProjectKind.scala:126)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.project.impl.simple.SimpleDependencyManager.reloadDependencies(SimpleProjectKind.scala:120)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.project.impl.simple.SimpleDependencyManager.start(SimpleProjectKind.scala:114)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.WeaveLanguageServer.$anonfun$initialized$1(WeaveLanguageServer.scala:232)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.jobs.JobManagerService$$anon$3.doTheJob(JobManagerService.scala:100)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.jobs.Job.run(JobManagerService.scala:122)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.jobs.JobManagerService.execute(JobManagerService.scala:43)
    at org.mule.weave.lsp.jobs.JobManagerService$$anon$1.run(JobManagerService.scala:23)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven
    at org.pf4j.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:144)
    ... 17 more
ott 24, 2023 10:42:41 AM org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint getArguments
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: How did you install Anypoint Code Builder?

Comment: With extension feature from Visual Studio Code. My Anypoint Extension Pack version is v1.0.5 @aled

Comment: Installing the Anypoint Extension Pack is the correct way, though it seems something is broken in your installation. Try uninstalling everything and install again following the steps from the documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-code-builder/start-acb

Comment: As u suggest, I tryed to reinstall but nothing change, but I solved changing the bussiness group, thanks for support!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Solved changing the bussiness group